# jQuery validator input type number 'e' symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Guys I'm using jQuery validator and it have a input field type number and when I enter 1e1 it says : invalid number , can anyone tell how can I prevent this message and allow numbers like 1e1 (10) ?? Workaround ?

Comment: can you specify which jQuery validator you are using? Are you using [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) ?

Comment: yes,Im using jQuery validation plugin.

Comment: so what do you want to allow '1e1' or '1e1 (10)' ?

Comment: I just want when user types 1e1 the value to be 10 ..

Comment: so you need to validate '1e1' using jQuery validator, right?

Comment: Yes but the thing is that when I type 1e1 it says that this is invalid number ...

Comment: ok so you need to add your own validation method by using `jQuery.validator.addMethod`. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

First assign value to var then validate it

```
value===Number(value).toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code to add validation method:

HTML:

```
<form id="frm">
  <input type="" name="txt" id="txt1">
  <button type="submit">save</button>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("exponential", function(value, element, params) {
  return this.optional(element) || $.isNumeric(value);
}, jQuery.validator.format("Please enter the correct value"));

$("#frm").validate({
  rules: {
    txt: {
      exponential: true
    },
  }
});
```

Comment: Okey I did it but now my javascript wont transfer my 1e1 into number when I display it its '1e1' again

Comment: what is your javascript code to convert `1e1` into number?

Comment: usually it is implemented by default when u enter 1e1 its converting it into 10 ans so on ... but I dont know why its not working now ... it was working before I switched to react.

Comment: jQuery.validator.addMethod("exponential", function(value, element, params) {
            console.log(Number(value));
            return this.optional(element) || Number(value);
        }, jQuery.validator.format("Please enter the correct value"));

Comment: When I console log it its okey but when I display it in my react component which is table its like '1e1' insted of 10

Comment: The above code in my answer is only used to validate input field, not to convert it. You can covert it by using `Number('1e1')`. I think you are already using same.